# Not able to perform selection in a multiple canvas application

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I am developing an application using Jquery's Fabric.js and HTML5 (Canvas) and having 2 canvas. Using "Display" property (CSS) I am displaying only one canvas at a time. 
The First canvas is working fine. But when I display 2nd canvas, the selection (dragging mouse on canvas) is disabled. I am not able to select any object on the canvas and also the selection area (which comes by dragging mouse) is not drawing.

Below is my code snippet:

HTML:
 `<div id="divCanvas" style="overflow:scroll;width:665px; height:570px">
       <canvas id="FrontCanvas"></canvas>
       <canvas id="BackCanvas"></canvas>
 </div>`

Javascript:
`$("#btnRotate").click(function () {
       if ($("#c").parent().hasClass("visible")) {
             $("#c").parent().addClass("invisible").removeClass("visible");
             $("#cb").parent().addClass("visible").removeClass("invisible");
       }
       else {
             $("#c").parent().addClass("visible").removeClass("invisible");
             $("#cb").parent().addClass("invisible").removeClass("visible");
       }
 });`

Thanks

Comment: can anyone help me in solving this issue?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Answer........Used calcOffset()

`$("#btnRotate").click(function () {
                if ($("#c").parent().hasClass("visible")) {
                    $("#c").parent().addClass("invisible").removeClass("visible");
                    $("#cb").parent().addClass("visible").removeClass("invisible");
                }
                else {
                    $("#c").parent().addClass("visible").removeClass("invisible");
                    $("#cb").parent().addClass("invisible").removeClass("visible");
                }
                canvas.calcOffset();
                canvasBack.calcOffset();
            });`